# What are dog tag + bow + no kill servers?

Tags: terminology, battlefield-4

When I browse online servers I see many examples of low population servers with a description such as:

> dog tags no killing

or

> dog tags / bow - no killing

When I join and get one kill I often get kicked by the admin.  I have also been kicked within two minutes of joining (despite not killing anyone).  I have tried following people around but I cannot figure out what they are doing.

I have experienced this on the Xbox One but this may also occur on other platforms.

Why are there so many of these servers and what are people doing in them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those servers dedicate themselves to players who want to meet the 4 Phantom assignment requirements.
You need to find 4 dogtags, that rarely randomly spawn on Final Stand maps.

Later you need 4 people with different found dogtags and camos to get into secret room to unlock the assignment.

Reward for the Phantom assignment is the Phantom Bow.

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick google search and found out that those servers are mainly for stats-padding/boosting.

Basically, these servers are for people that want to get a dog-tag (or similar) the quick and easy way.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure it is boosting-related but just couldn't figure out why it is popular... and why no kills.  I have only ever known one way to get dog tags in any Battlefield/Bad Company game and that is with knife kills.

Comment: I wonder if it is one of the Phantom assignments.  In Battlelog I have 4 with "?" as the requirements.  I'll do some more digging later.

Comment: Yes, it seems that many are for the final stand dogtags.

Comment: @CamelCase for your information, I have already answered a question related to the phantom assignments you can check it out